# HTML label constants without javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a python application which sends personalized HTML emails, it loads an HTML template with labels like name, date...

```
<label id="name"></label>
<label id="date"></label>
...
```

And at the end of the loaded HTML I add a script with the value of these labels

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = 'Mau';
    document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = '19-02-2019';
...

</script>
</html>
```

If I open the generated HTML with a web browser I see the labels correctly replaced with the values

The problem is that I discovered that email clients won't run the script, showing the default label value.

I wonder how can I define constants at the beginning of the HTML file without using a script?

I know that I can load the HTML in python and search for the variables line per line, but this will be time-consuming because they're like 20 labels in the email.

Each variable is not always in the same line because I use different templates and welcome text.

So I was wondering if I can define something at the beginning or at the end of the HTML that I can just append to the HTML before sending it?

Something like:

Definitions added by python

name_constant = "Mau"
date_constant = "12_12_2019"
...

So that I don't need to write anything in the body template

label id="name_lbl">name_constant

...

Thanks

Comment: Why not just fill in the label content from your Python code?

Comment: Create the email using Python string formatting to fill in the labels.

Comment: If the requirement is to only display the content and the client processes `<style>` elements you can use CSS.

Comment: @Intervalia currently I'm doing it this way, but I have to load all the HTML line by line searching for the text to be replaced because they're not always in the same line :/ I was looking for something that I can add at the beginning or end of the HTML file

Comment: @guest271314 I have seen style but I tought that it was only for size, color... I'll take a deeeper look. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't have variables in HTML.
HTML is markup language itself. Not more.

What you can do though, is make those labels contain some placeholders for values.
Then you'd replace the placeholders before returning HTML from your back-end.

Something like this:
HTML:

`<label id="name">##LABEL_NAME_VALUE##</label>`
`<label id="date">##LABEL_DATE_VALUE##</label>`

And then in your python script, which return the HTML just replace placeholders with actual values.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, currently I'm doing it this way, but I have to load all the HTML line by line searching for the text to be replaced because they're not always in the same line :/ I was looking for something that I can add at the beginning or end of the HTML file

Answer (score 0):

## [`::before` & `::after`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/)

If JavaScript isn't feasible and I have no idea what Python can do (Python tag should be posted), CSS pseudo-elements would work since the label content is constant. BTW if you have 20 labels with the same text you should use classes instead. The following demo shows the use of ids as you have it in the code provided in the question and the use of classes as well.

### Demo

```css
#name::after {
  content: 'Mau'
}

#date::after {
  content: '19-02-2019'
}

.name::before {
  content: 'Foo'
}

.date::before {
  content: '04-02-2019'
}

/* For Demo Purposes */
label {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<label id="name"></label>
<label id="date"></label>


<label class="name"></label>
<label class="date"></label>
<label class="name"></label>
<label class="date"></label>
<label class="name"></label>
<label class="date"></label>
<label class="name"></label>
<label class="date"></label>
<label class="name"></label>
<label class="date"></label>
```

Comment: Hi, I did the test and again in the local html it works!! it changes the displayed names but in the received email the labels are empty

Comment: https://i45.photobucket.com/albums/f68/EinSoldiatGott/received%20email.png

Comment: Note, that HTML in Emails is limited on functionality.
There it is literally just markup. Do not expect any JS or some fancy animations to work in Emails.
I believe, it is some safety limitation, which you have to take into account.

Comment: @Anatolyevich This is CSS which is neither HTML, JS, nor fancy animation.